# R: ESS shell.exec speed

Tags: r, ess

I am using ESS in Windows XP. I have noticed that `shell.exec` is much slower with ESS than with RGui (the problem occurs when I try `help(ls)` for example, the help is displayed much faster in RGui, I tracked it down and it is due to `shell.exec`). Is there any reason for this? How can I fix it? My default browser is Firefox.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what Firefox has to do with this.